# copy/paste rows´ cell from a column to another one - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data on a spreadsheet. In particular i need the TIME that is in the first column and in the second one depending on the time, for strange reasons when i import the txt file into excel if the time is from 10 AM to 23.59 the time is on the column A otherwise time in in B.
I´m trying to make a VBA script that could allow me to put all the data in the same column (A).
My idea is :
 - for all the rows in the colum A
 - if the cell is empty copy the value of the B cell (same row) in the actual cell (ex. if A1 is empty then copy B1 in A1)
 - Stop

Sub Test()

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim x, y As Integer
Dim rng As String

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
' count numer of recorsd (in the first column) - check the range
lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

For i = 1 To lastRow
   If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, i))) Then Range(Cells(2, i)).Select: Range (Cells     (1, i)).Copy: Range(Cells(1, i)).PasteSpecial:    Range(Cells(2, i)).Clear
Next i
```

End Sub

I tryed to do somethings but it shows up an error: 
´run-time error ´1004´:
Application-defined or object-defined error

Any ideas?

Comment: You should also change `i, x, y` from `Integer`s to `Long`s. Integers will fail after row `32,767`, and they are converted to `Long`s internally anyway: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa164754.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of things with your code. First, the variable `lastrow` is counting the number of items in Column B, does that does not necessary mean that it will give you the last row number so I suggested a change in my code below to fix this. Also, your range references for Cells have the column/row swapped, I fixed that as well in the code below. Finally, the reason why you are receiving the error is because your reference to the cell is incorrect. Here is my recommendation and should do what you are looking for

```
Sub Main()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
' count numer of recorsd (in the first column) - check the range
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Set rng = Cells(i, 1)
    If IsEmpty(rng) Then
        Cells(i, 2).Copy
        Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial
        Cells(i, 2).Clear
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `IsEmpty` is not referring to Cells in the sheet, but to uninitialized variables. You can simply check whether a cell contains an empty string. Hope the following code helps:

```
Sub Copy()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To lastRow
    If (Cells(i, 1) = "") Then
        Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 2)
        Cells(i, 2).Clear
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

It checks the cells in column A for empty strings and copies the value of the same row cell in column b, which will be deleted afterwards.

Comment: this was working but it was pastingdata in a strange format, like numeric one with comme. But thank you for help!

Comment: comme? what do you mean?

Comment: comma :) it was a mistake.